# Does Pythonanywhere support MongoDB Atlas hosted Database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Does pythonanywhere.com support MongoDB Atlas hosted Database?

I can connect from my local machine. But, from pythonanywhere.com is showing the following error:

```
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-01.x6cgk.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused,cluster0-shard-00-00.x6cgk.mongodb.net:27017
: [Errno 111] Connection refused,cluster0-shard-00-02.x6cgk.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Can you please help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It works for a paid accounts on PythonAnywhere. You also need to add ip address to the allowed list. Take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MongoDB/